# Define the set C with given operations (Linear Algebra)

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-set-theory, vector-spaces

Define the set $\{C = (x,y) : x,y \in \Bbb R\}$ with the operations as
$$
(x_1, y_1) \oplus (x_2, y_2) = (x_1 + x_2 + 1, y_1 + y_2 + 1)
$$ 
and $\alpha$ $\otimes$ ($x_1$, $y_1$) = ($\alpha$ $x_1$ + $\alpha$ - 1, $\alpha$ $y_1$ + $\alpha$ - 1),
for all ($x_1$, $y_1$), ($x_2$, $y_2$) $\epsilon$ C and $\alpha$ $\epsilon$ ${R}$: Is it a vector space? Justify your answer.

I understand how to figure out if something is a vector space, I'm mostly confused by the use of the direct addition and multiplication signs because I was under the impression that the direct addition of ($x_1$, $y_1$) $\oplus$ ($x_2$, $y_2$) is always ($x_1$ + $x_2$, $y_1$ + $y_2$). So how would I define the set in this situation?

Comment: The notation $\oplus$ in the question does not correspond to your notion of direct sum. It is just a notation for anew operation.

Comment: Just as $\otimes$ does not have its usual meaning as a tensor product in this context, so does $\oplus$ not have its usual meaning as a direct sum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** (For an expedient proof).  Note that for $x_1,x_2 \in \Bbb R$,
$$
\alpha x_1 + \alpha - 1 = \alpha(x_1 + 1) - 1\\
x_1 + x_2 + 1 = (x_1 + 1) + (x_2 + 1) - 1.
$$

---

Another perspective: if $\phi:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ is defined by $\phi(x) = x - 1$, then we have
$$
(x_1,x_2) \oplus (y_1,y_2) = (f^{-1}(f(x_1) + f(x_2)), f^{-1}(f(y_1) + f(y_2))),\\
\alpha \otimes (x_1 ,x_2) = (f^{-1}(\alpha f(x_1)), f^{-1}(\alpha(x_2))).
$$
In other words, $\oplus$ and $\otimes$ are addition and mulitplication redefined via a [transport of structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_of_structure).  See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3479540/81360) and [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3478301/81360) for the same idea with a more complicated $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$.